# NVME SSD upgrade options for Dell Inspiron 15 3581

Tags: ssd, dell-inspiron, nvme

Model: Dell Inspiron 15 3581.
Question:

What maximum size M.2 NVME SSD can I attach? Dell manual says 256 GB.

Specifications as under:
Processor
2.30 gigahertz Intel Core i3-7020U
128 kilobyte primary memory cache
512 kilobyte secondary memory cache
3 megabyte tertiary memory cache
64-bit ready
Multi-core (2 total)
Hyper-threaded (4 total)
[Cache and TLB]
L1 Cache:   Instruction: 2 x 32 KBytes, Data: 2 x 32 KBytes
L2 Cache:   Integrated: 2 x 256 KBytes
L3 Cache:   3 MBytes
Instruction TLB:    2MB/4MB Pages, Fully associative, 8 entries
Data TLB:   4 KB Pages, 4-way set associative, 64 entries
Main circuit board
Board: Dell Inc. 0F8GH6 A00
Bus Clock: 100 megahertz
UEFI: Dell Inc. 1.17.0 03/24/2022
[Motherboard]
Motherboard Model: DELL 0F8GH6
Motherboard Chipset: Intel Kaby Lake-U + iHDCP 2.2 Premium PCH
Motherboard Slots: 6xPCI Express x1
PCI Express Version Supported: v3.0
USB Version Supported: v3.0
System Slots
Slot1
Slot Designation: Slot1
Slot Type: PCI Express
Slot Usage: In use
Slot Data Bus Width: 1x / x1
Slot Length: Long
Base Bus:Device:Function Number: 0:28:0
Slot2
Slot Designation: Slot2
Slot Type: PCI Express
Slot Usage: Empty
Slot Data Bus Width: 1x / x1
Slot Length: Short
Base Bus:Device:Function Number: 0:28:1
Slot3
Slot Designation: Slot3
Slot Type: PCI Express
Slot Usage: Empty
Slot Data Bus Width: 1x / x1
Slot Length: Short
Base Bus:Device:Function Number: 0:28:2
Slot1013/07/2022, 18:11 HWiNFO64 Report
file:///D:/galib20Laptop2/RMO/ICT/Computers/hwinfo.09072022.HTM 24/58
Slot Designation: Slot10
Slot Type: PCI Express
Slot Usage: Empty
Slot Data Bus Width: 1x / x1
Slot Length: Short
Base Bus:Device:Function Number: 0:29:1
Slot11
Slot Designation: Slot11
Slot Type: PCI Express
Slot Usage: Empty
Slot Data Bus Width: 1x / x1
Slot Length: Short
Base Bus:Device:Function Number: 0:29:2
Slot12
Slot Designation: Slot12
Slot Type: PCI Express
Slot Usage: Empty
Slot Data Bus Width: 1x / x1
Slot Length: Short
Base Bus:Device:Function Number: 0:29:3

Comment: NVMe SSD can be of any size (as long as the physical dimensions match). Try to get an SSD that does not consume too much power then it will also stay cooler. Internal GPU chips in notebooks are to may knowledge nearly always soldered to the mainboard, so no possibility to add or replace one.

Comment: I am concerned that some motherboard specification(s), limits the size of the NVME SSD. I tried to look up chipset, bandwidth, PCIe gen, etc. Still no clue.